# C# / ASP.NET - list of objects to list

Tags: asp.net, list, hyperlink, label

I have list of objects.

Object have three properties:

```
name            url                 info
google          www.google.com      search engine
```

I'm trying to build list, where I can put those objects.
I was planning to use **linkbutton** and **label**. 
How I can add those to list and which type of list is best for this?

ListView, DataGrid or etc?

My idea is this:

```
Linkbutton  label
google      search engine
etc...      etc...
```

Can anyone show code example?

Comment: This is what call a chain-reaction question because it generates one question after the other, if you don't know how to make a list and bind it to a data-bound control...how are you gonna be capable of building databinding expressions to bind inner controls. I recommend you read a tutorial

Comment: Have actually made an attempt at this yet?  It's hard to decide how much of an answer to give, if we don't know how far you are / what you understand about the process.  Perhaps show your attempt, and mention where it is that you have gotten stuck?